# Client side validation not working for the custom attribute in MVC3 razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a custom attribute to read the value of string length value from the config file. I am using it on a partial view which gets loaded using ajax get.

Here is the code of my custom attribute:

```
public class ConfigMaxLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute,IClientValidatable
    {
        private readonly int _maxLength;

        public ConfigMaxLengthAttribute(string key)
            : base(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]))
        {
            _maxLength = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var strValue = value as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
            {
                var len = strValue.Length;
                return len <= _maxLength;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
               {
                   ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message",
                   ValidationType = "stringmaxlength"
               };
        }
    }
```

and in the JS file I have included the following code:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
jQuery.validator.addMethod('greaterThan', function (value, element, params) {
    return value.length>200;
}, '');

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('stringmaxlength', {}, function (options) {
        options.rules['greaterThan'] = true;
        options.messages['greaterThan'] = options.messages;
    });
```

This is generating the following markup for the field in the html:

```
<textarea cols="28" data-val="true" data-val-stringmaxlength="Notes entered cannot be more than 200 characters." id="UserNote" name="UserNote" rows="2" >
</textarea>
```

I have included this JS file in the view. In my web.config file client side validations are enabled..

All my client side validations using data annotaions are working except this custom attribute one..

I have no clue how to proceed further, any help please...

Answer (score 0):

Loading partials via Ajax requires that you reparse the new content so that any unobtrusive validation attributes in the HTML are understood by the validation framework. I'm assuming you're using jquery validate.

So, if you were loading some content which contained a form into some container div then:

```
var form = $(newContentContainerDiv).find("form");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

...this would reparse the validation attributes in the new form.

This is a requirement when loading new content via Ajax as the validation f/w won't know about it.

If you want to test that your attribute is definitely working then just include the partial in some regular view (i.e. don't use Ajax) and if your attribute works then it should validate without any additional work.